# Помогите оптимизировать код зацикленной перемотки товаров на PHP

Tags: php

Помогите оптимизировать зацикленную перемотку цветов.

 Есть такая таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть такие переключатели:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас использую такой код:

```
$mysqli = new PDO("mysql:host=$sql_hostname;dbname=$sql_database", $sql_username, $sql_password, $options);

$res = $mysqli->query("call PC_product_list($vendor_code)")->fetchAll();
$count = $mysqli->query("call PC_product_list($vendor_code)")->rowCount();

$key = NULL;
$vc_next = '';
$vc_back = '';

foreach ($res as $val_key => $value) {
    if ($value['vendor_code'] == 4059729329264)
        $key = $val_key;
}

if ($count == $key)
    $next = 0;
else
    $next = $key + 1;

if ($key == 0)
    $back = $count - 1;
else
    $back = $key - 1;

$vc_next = $res[$next]['vendor_code'];
$vc_back = $res[$back]['vendor_code'];

echo "next -> $vc_next";
echo "\n";
echo "back -> $vc_back";
```

Сам массив:

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["vendor_code"]=>
    int(4059729329264)
    ["brand"]=>
    string(7) "BIELITA"
    ["color"]=>
    string(3) "010"
    ["is_active"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["vendor_code"]=>
    int(4059729329301)
    ["brand"]=>
    string(7) "BIELITA"
    ["color"]=>
    string(3) "020"
    ["is_active"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["vendor_code"]=>
    int(4059729329349)
    ["brand"]=>
    string(7) "BIELITA"
    ["color"]=>
    string(3) "030"
    ["is_active"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["vendor_code"]=>
    int(4059729329387)
    ["brand"]=>
    string(7) "BIELITA"
    ["color"]=>
    string(3) "040"
    ["is_active"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(4) {
    ["vendor_code"]=>
    int(4059729329424)
    ["brand"]=>
    string(7) "BIELITA"
    ["color"]=>
    string(3) "050"
    ["is_active"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [5]=>
  array(4) {
    ["vendor_code"]=>
    int(4059729329462)
    ["brand"]=>
    string(7) "BIELITA"
    ["color"]=>
    string(3) "060"
    ["is_active"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [6]=>
  array(4) {
    ["vendor_code"]=>
    int(4059729329509)
    ["brand"]=>
    string(7) "BIELITA"
    ["color"]=>
    string(3) "070"
    ["is_active"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [7]=>
  array(4) {
    ["vendor_code"]=>
    int(4059729329547)
    ["brand"]=>
    string(7) "BIELITA"
    ["color"]=>
    string(3) "080"
    ["is_active"]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

Comment: Что есть "дополнительная нагрузка на сервер"?

Comment: @ArchDemon, случайно осталось. Исправил.

Comment: А зачем вы хотите оптимизировать?

Comment: @ArchDemon, мне кажется есть более правильный подход к реализации =\

Comment: Что даст вам "правильность" подхода? Улучшение каких метрик вы хотите добиться? Какие метрики вас на текущий момент не удовлетворяют?

Comment: @ArchDemon, ну меня в принципе все удовлетворяет. Просто думал может есть альтернативный подход

Comment: Если вас всё удовлетворяет, то ничего менять не нужно

Comment: @ArchDemon, спасибо за ответ  =}